# Present Modal for Image Select Erases UI

Tags: ios, swift

I have  a very simple View controller below. The UI is literally just a single button with the tab bar at the bottom.

```
import UIKit

class ImageAdderViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    @IBAction func ButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
        self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Once the select image from photo library is selected, if I click cancel or select an image it returns to the view. But the view is now empty except for the tab view.

Here is where my confusion begins:

1. This code works on an empty project with just one controller.
2. This code works when I segue to this controller from a different controller that has no tab bar at the bottom. At this point the UI with the button that we have segued to also has no tab bar.
3. This code does not work when I segue to the controller via  a controller that has the tab bar.

All segues are push Show (e.g. Push) segues.

In short the same UIViewController works when segued to by one view but not when segued to by a different view.

**EDIT 1 Specific Questions**

How do I make the view controller work even when segued to by a view controller with a tab bar? Could the tab bar interfere with the `presentViewController` code?

**My Guess**

Somehow something from the previous controller with the tab bar is messing up the code on the viewcontroller with the load button, and that something seems to be entering with the tab bar when the Show occurs. How do I prevent this?

**EDIT 2 More clarification**

When I click cancel or select an image, the view controller that it returns me too is now empty. The button is missing. When I add labels to the view, all added those disappear as well, and it is just white, except the tab bar at the bottom. This does not occur if I segue to the load image view controller from a view without the tab bar.

**EDIT 3**

The View that does **not** bring the tab bar with it when segued from, is **not** segued to via a navigation controller.

The View that does bring the tab bar with it when segued from, is segued to via a navigation controller.

The Former view functionality does not cause the error. But it does not bring the tab bar

The Latter functionality has brings the tab bar and I want that.

**EDIT 4**

Changing the segue to a modal present on the UI which has the tab eliminates the tab bar but does not solve to UI deletion problem. This means that merely the presence of the tab bar is not causing the problem.

**EDIT 5**

If I completely delete the navigation controller in the storyboard it all works, but the tab bar is gone. How can I make it work with the navigation controller?

Comment: Please ask your question clearly

Comment: what is your problem? what happens when you select an image from gallery?

Comment: can you show me the code?

Comment: @GaneshKumar  what code? I have sent all the code for the UIViewController. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38293815/selecting-photo-returns-to-blank-ui this question has all the code for other views.

Comment: @GaneshKumar Most of the "code" which I do not have displayed above is just segues in the storyboard